# How to change the PCI Device number in windows

Tags: pci

I am having PCI based device attached to my system, the driver is installed correctly and everything is fine there, when i open the device manager and look at the property of device it shows

> **"Location : PCI bus 5, device 5, function 0"**

but my source code is written in such a way that i need to have it at device location 0 or 1 in order to access the hardware correctly.

can anyone help me with, how to change that number or how to install device in such a way that i get the following configuration

> **Location : PCI bus 5, device 0, function 0"**

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This seems fairly obvious to me, but... change your source code so it doesn't "need to have it at device location 0 or 1"?

Comment: hmm, i have several devices connected on PCI (let's say 8 of them) instead of just one and i want them in order for source to access them in loop and access them simultaneously.

Comment: hmm, so it seems you need to change your code to properly address them (and change your question to explain how it's wrong). I still don't see the problem here - change your code to look in the proper places. What's missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Ideal fix would be to change your code. I see that for some reason (that I dont quiet understand) you are restricted not to do so.

The max that can be achieved in software is to have bus no.s changed. You cant have the DEVICE number or FUNCTION no. changed in software.